# Graphical Probabilistic Representation of Naive Bayes

Tags: conditional-probability, independence, naive-bayes, graphical-model

Given the Naive Bayes graphical representation below, I want to calculate $P(X|Y_1,Y_2)$.

Are the calculations below correct?

[image]

The factored joint distribution regarding the system is:
$$P(X,Y_1,Y_2)=P(X) \cdot P(Y_1|X) \cdot P(Y_2|X)$$ 
$$\frac{P(X,Y_1,Y_2)}{P(X)}=P(Y_1|X) \cdot P(Y_2|X)$$ 
$$P(Y_1,Y_2|X)= P(Y_1|X) \cdot P(Y_2|X)$$ 
Using Bayes rule to flip the left hand side:
$$\frac{P(X|Y_1,Y_2) \cdot P(Y_1,Y_2)}{P(X)}= P(Y_1|X) \cdot P(Y_2|X)$$ 
$$P(X|Y_1,Y_2) = \frac{P(Y_1|X) \cdot P(Y_2|X) \cdot P(X)}{P(Y_1,Y_2)}$$ 
$$P(X|Y_1,Y_2) = \frac{P(Y_1|X) \cdot P(Y_2|X) \cdot P(X)}{P(Y_1) \cdot P(Y_2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Up to the last line, like [Henry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2958/henry) already pointed out, is all correct. What you could write is,

$$
P(X|Y_{1},Y_{2}) = \frac{P(Y_{1},Y_{2}|X)P(X)}{\sum_{X}P(Y_{1},Y_{2}|X)P(X)} =  \frac{P(Y_{1},|X)P(Y_{2},|X)P(X)}{\sum_{X}P(Y_{1},|X)P(Y_{2},|X)P(X)}
$$

$Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are only independent given $X$.

Answer (score 0):

No, the move from your penultimate equation to the final equation has an error.

In general you should not say  $P(Y_1,Y_2)= P(Y_1)P(Y_2)$.

Answer (score -1):

According to the Naive Bayesian graph, the covariate $Y_1$ is **independent** of the covariate $Y_2$.

Therefore $P(Y_1|X) \cdot P(Y_2|X)=P(Y_1,Y_2|X)$  and $P(Y_1,Y_2) = P(Y_1) \cdot P(Y_2)  $

Implementing these into your last equation, you can see that:

$$P(X|Y_1,Y_2) = \frac{P(Y_1,Y_2|X) \cdot P(X)}{P(Y_1,Y_2)}  $$

Comment: Don't know much about Naive Bayes. However, looking at the graph, Y1 and Y2 are only conditionally independent given X. Think of them as points uniformly distributed on a frisbee, and X as the co-ordinates of where the frisbee lands